# Android L2TP connection to server

Tags: java, android, connection, authorization, vpn

This is my letter of hope. I'm using android 4.* to create a l2tp connection to the server. The problem is in authorization. I have a server key , user login and password. I search any solution along the internet, not for android only but for java at all, and didnt find any code sample for start. I have no idea how I can authorize on server. ToyVpn in android samples didnt help, its just sample of regular connection(without any authorization). Please, somebody, help! I'll be grateful for for any useful information in this question.

Comment: Share your research and how you did that.

Comment: That's impossible, you can do it by using system settings. Creating app, which use user name, password, Pre shared key and ip adress is forbidden by Android system